# What's the earliest source to bless children on Friday night with Yivarechicha?

Tags: minhag, history

I wanted to know the earliest source to bless our children with yivarechicha... I've seen this minhag brought from the Yavetz. I wanted to know the earliest source.
(Im asking specifically on blessing them with yivarechicha as opposed to blessing them in general)

Comment: The Maaver Yabok was 100 years before the Yaavetz and mentions it but I can’t vouch that he’s the earliest

Comment: @Dov you're saying yisimeach.. and yivarechicha orginated at one time?